# web scraping with scrapy. how to define an xpath wildcard for numbers?

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

What I'm trying to do is grab the names of the different employment opportunities from the [stackoverflow careers subsection](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs).

the xpath of the elements I want, according to my chrome plugin which magically tells you the xpath for a selected element, looks like this:

```
//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/h3/a

//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/h3/a

//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/h3/a

//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/h3/a
```

I can pull out the titles individually with this command to the [scrapy shell](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html):

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/h3/a').extract()
```

and so on, by switching the number of the last div[] element.

My question is, how can I make a generalizable command that will extract all of the titles on a page?

I had a look on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp) about xpath syntax but I didn't see anything about a kind of wildcard for numbers, is that such a thing? Is this a reasonable way of extracting all the different names of jobs?

The html looks like this:

```
[u'<a class='job-link' href='/jobs/92881/software-engineer-java-m-w-advitec-informatik-gmbh?a=v9gjNYx3zGg&amp;so=i' title='Software Engineer JAVA (m/w)'>Software Engineer JAVA (m/w)</a>']
```

which is not completely useless, i could work with that, and then extract it further with jsoup or something, but i need it for all the jobs and not just one, you know?

also... is there a way in the scrapy shell to make them appear with a newline after?

Comment: `//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/h3/a`

Comment: Or even `//*[@id="content"]//div/h3/a`

Comment: Or even `//*[@id="content"]//h3/a`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop over the titles like so:

```
xpath_jobs_sel = './/div[contains(@class,"listResults")]//a[@class="job-link"]'
for sel in response.xpath(xpath_jobs_sel):
    title = sel.xpath('./@title').extract()
```

The good thing is, you can nest `XPaths`. The first `XPath` yields a list with `Selectors`. Notice the `dot` at the beginning of the inner statement. It means that this statement is relative to the first!

Comment: is it possible to use that in the shell? or i guess i need to write it into a file?

Comment: Just tested it. It works in the shell. You want to add a `print title` statement so that you can see the output.